# Acces mysql value in html to send to php file through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to get the value of id so that I can delete the data from mysql based on the id number

This is a project for events, the main idea here is I want to get the id number of the event based on the clicked button, so that I can update/delete the event based on the id number.

Code for displaying details

```
  <?php $sql= "SELECT event_name, event_date, event_id FROM events WHERE event_status=0";
  $result= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);?>

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   echo ' 

      <div class="pending-card">

        <div class="pending-image">

        </div>';

     echo "  <div class='pending-title'>
          <h1>{$row["event_name"]}</h1>
        </div>";

       echo " <div class='pending-des'>
          <p>{$row["event_date"]}</p>
          <button class='choice-pending'><a href='detail.php'>Read More...</a></button>
          <input style='display: none;' type='text' id='test-pend' value='{$row["event_id"]}'>
        </div>

      </div>
    ";
}
```

Jquery code

Here I tried to check if this works by making an alert, but after i press the button, the id number that came out is not correspond with the button i click

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.choice-pending').click(function(){
    alert("Value: " +  $('#test-pend').val());

});
});
```

Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong

Example, the event i pressed is suppose to be 34, but the alert shows 26 which is the first event id in the code for displaying details

Comment: `<button>` should not contain `<a>`, that's very confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **data-*** attribute in your element.

**Based on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp**

> The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page
>   or application.
>
> The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data
>   attributes on all HTML elements.
>
> The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript to
>   create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or
>   server-side database queries).
>
> The data-* attributes consist of two parts:
>
> The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must
>   be at least one character long after the prefix "data-" The attribute
>   value can be any string Note: Custom attributes prefixed with "data-"
>   will be completely ignored by the user agent.

```
<button class="choice-pending" data-event-id="<?= $row['event_id']; ?>">Read More...</button>
```

Then in your script you can access the clicked button:

```
$(".choice-pending").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-event-id') !== undefined) {
        // You can do ajax call here to your detail.php

        // Or you can simply create a hidden field inside your form, assigned the data-event-id value to it, then $("form").submit(); 

    } else {
        /** Error message here, maybe? */

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove your anchor tag inside button and use only anchor or button and print your html with assign some dynamic class or id into each to make them unique like this.

```
<div class='pending-des'>
   <p>{$row["event_date"]}</p>
   <a class='choice-pending-{$row["event_id"]}' href='detail.php'>Read More...</a>
   <input style='display: none;' type='text' id='test-pend-{$row["event_id"]}' value='{$row["event_id"]}'>
</div>
```

Now bind click event on it-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.pending-des').each(function(){
       $(this).on('click', 'a[class^=choice-pending-]', function(){
          alert($(this).find('input[id^=test-pend-]').val());
       });

   });

});
```